# Delete [emr] - it's a duplicate of [amazon-emr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

Those are synonyms. I suggest to merge them. Leave [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) and delete [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr), as [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) is easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another [elastic-map-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce) as well. Both of them are now remapped to [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr)

The number of posts at the time of synonymization was:

- [elastic-map-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce) × 480
- [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr) × 1304
- [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr) × 1156

After synonymization, there are 2,940 questions.