# There’s more of the [amazon] to cut down

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This picks up where [my previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334050/1558022) left off – there are still Amazon services that have multiple tags hanging around.

- **[amazon-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) (440)** / [cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudwatch) (80)
- [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam) (766) / **[aws-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-iam) (21)**
- **[amazon-dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-dynamodb) (3201)** / [dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamodb) (111)
- **[amazon-elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elastic-beanstalk) (351)** / [elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk) (2984)
- **[amazon-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cognito) (787)** / [aws-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cognito) (48)
- **[amazon-elb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elb) (689)** / [elastic-load-balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-load-balancer) (74)

and there are other Meta Qs about similar duplicate tags:

- [Synonyms: amazon-mws and mws](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290699/1558022)
- [Merge [emr] into [amazon-emr]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343102/1558022)
- [Merge [cloudformation] into [amazon-cloudformation]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341927/1558022)

Based on the tag wikis and looking through some of the questions in each tag, it looks like these are indeed just duplicates. For the sake of consistency (and making things easier to find!), we should retag and/or synonymise these duplicates.

I’ve highlighted in bold what I think the canonical tag should be – using an `amazon-` or `aws-` prefix for consistency with other AWS tags, and choosing a prefix based on Amazon’s preferred branding.

Comment: Ugh, I have to upvote a request with that horribly dark title. Well, Stack Overflow comes before life.

Comment: @Gimby yes it's absolutely horrible. I'd say not even funny...But then my comedian kicks in and suggests that you change it to be in Portuguese

Comment: @DaniloRamirez what joke is there in Portuguese which doesn't exist in English?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The official language of Brazil, the country with a lot of the Amazon, is Portuguese.

Comment: [tag:aws-mobilehub] & [tag:amazon-mobilehub] and [tag:aws-ecs] & [tag:amazon-ecs] have also both cropped up again since the original post, since they were only removed, not synonymized.

Comment: @Ullallulloo, [tag:amazon-mobilehub] is already removed (perhaps someone retagged manually?). For [tag:aws-ecs] and [tag:amazon-ecs], both of them are sponsored tags, so I have to inform the SE team. I poked a CM regarding it. Once they respond, I'll synonymize both.

Comment: ... and [aws-ecs] is also done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace yourselves for more heat ... more of amazon has been cutdown:

```
[cloudwatch] x 69 ----------------> [amazon-cloudwatch] x 1091  

[iam] x 0  -----------------------> [amazon-iam] x 1537
[aws-iam] x 126 ---------------/

[dynamodb] -----------------------> /dev/null

[elastic-beanstalk] × 4823 -------> [amazon-elastic-beanstalk] × 651    

[cognito] x 79 -------------------> [amazon-cognito] x 1889
[aws-cognito] x 844 -----------/

[elastic-load-balancer] × 385 ----> [amazon-elb] × 1062 

[mws] × 19 -----------------------> [amazon-mws] × 684

[elastic-map-reduce] × 480 -------> [amazon-emr] × 1156
[emr] × 1304
```

Sub notes :

1. [dynamodb] was burninated or retagged at some point
2. [beanstalk] created a small problem as it was synonymized to [elastic-beanstalk], I  merged [beanstalk] to [elastic-beanstalk] and then added [amazon-elasticbeanstalk] as a synonym, and then reversed the synonyms.
3. [aws-cognito] meta-post: [Synonym/Retag request for [aws-cognito] -> [amazon-cognito]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366061/4099593)
4. [emr] meta-post: [Delete [emr] - it's a duplicate of [amazon-emr]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334617/4099593)
5. In all the cases, the [amazon-*] named tag has been kept, just to make it clear and keep it consistent across.

Comment: is there a reason to keep [iam], which is an industry abbreviation pointing to a company's product? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up @A.J., feel free to post a new meta question instead. I'm no longer a moderator here at Stack Overflow, so don't have the powers to do anything. :)