# Tag Synonym: [Amazon-Redshift] and [AWS-Redshift]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

When searching through the top posts on Stack Overflow, I found this question ([How to execute Redshift queries in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393004/how-to-execute-redshift-queries-in-parallel)) that has the tags [amazon-redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-redshift) and [aws-redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-redshift). These seem redundant to me.

Currently [aws-redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-redshift) only has 3 followers and 4 questions, so I would propose its removal in favor of [amazon-redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-redshift) which has 839 followers and 2.5k questions, however, I don't yet have the privilege of doing this myself.

Comment: header needs to be wittier

Comment: I've suggested the synonym. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-redshift/synonyms Just needs 4 up votes now.

Comment: Agree with the synonym proposal and upvoted it. Need a beacon to attract a few more AWS answerers and it'll be live. :)

Comment: If anyone doubts this, `amazon-s3`, `amazon-ec2`, `amazon-lambda`, are likewise linked, although the direction is not consistent. `amazon-cognito` is also a candidate for this. I imagine it might be worth doing a pass for all amazon/aws connections.

Comment: @AlexL how about shift AWS-Redshift?

Comment: Same shift different tag

Comment: I have a list of suggestions for some other Amazon/AWS-related synonyms: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343482/1558022

Comment: @Matt I assume you meant the German word "Tag"?

Comment: @AlexL not much better incorporating shift tbh

Comment: @ajb play on words for "Same s**t different day"

Answer (score 2):

**The synonym has now been created, according to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-redshift/synonyms.**

In the future, for very small tags like this (4 questions), it may be simpler to just retag the questions and let the Roomba delete the empty tag.  If it gets recreated, *then* you have a strong argument for creating the synonym.