# Synonym/Retag request for [aws-cognito] -> [amazon-cognito]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Reasons for this request:

- Both tags refer to the same service, officially named "Amazon Cognito", it's confusing to have a duplicate
- [amazon-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cognito) has a more fleshed-out tag info
- [amazon-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cognito) more accurately reflects the product name
- [amazon-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cognito) has ~1500 questions vs [aws-cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cognito)'s ~600

Comment: Just FYI, there's a third tag: [tag:cognito]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synonym was proposed by John Rotenstein on Jul 5 '17 at 11:32. However, it was never approved (it did get 1 single vote of approval).

I noticed this request when I was [informed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43966407#43966407) of this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20885260) that added the tag. I have now approved the tag synonym, in the following way:

```
[cognito] x 79        ---------> [amazon-cognito] x 1889
[aws-cognito] x 844   ----/
```